# syntax error, unexpected end of file in laravel 5.2 controller

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

Sorry for posting simple issue which I failed to find out:

```
public function show(){

function display(){

    $q = DB::table('posts')->get();

    return $q;
  }
    $m      = new Post;
    $data  = $m->display();
    foreach($data as $row)
    {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $row->id ?></td>
                <td><?= $row->name ?></td>
                <td><?= $row->description ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?

    }
    exit();
}
```

mainly the problem I am facing with the foreach loop in controller wich I am trying to display with ajax request in view.

Comment: Why are you defining function inside another function?

Comment: You should check out the Laravel documentation concerning Eloquent and Models: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent

Comment: lol, sorry for this, i actually placed it in model but put it here to make it understand by others. anyways thanks for your suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
public function show() {

        function display() {

            $q = DB::table('posts')->get();

            return $q;
        }

        $m = new Post;
        $data = $m->display();
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $row->id ?></td>
                <td><?= $row->name ?></td>
                <td><?= $row->description ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: Description wold help to understand how you solved the error.

Comment: thanks dear, got it, the error was with php tag, solved :-)